# When searching python version . getting some large content instead of python version

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface, python-3.8

I am trying to search for the python version in cmd , but I am getting a large chunk of data instead of the python version. Please inform me why I am getting this and the resolution of this.

```
C:\Users\vssnr>python -v
import _frozen_importlib   frozen
import _imp   builtin
import '_thread'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_io'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'nt'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'winreg'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external'   <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import _thread   previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref   previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import winreg   previously loaded ('winreg')
import 'winreg'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
  installing zipimport hook
import 'time'   <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport'   <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
  installed zipimport hook
```

and later it is checking the respective folders

Comment: Please do not upload pictures https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question, but to answer your question, you are using the wrong command. You need to use `python --version`.

Comment: `python -V`, not `python -v`

Comment: Thanks @annes, I have changed the pic to string output

Answer (score 1):

```
python --version
python -V

# output
# Python 2.7.18
```